# Adaptative Triggers with custom attached properties in Windows 10 UWP

Tags: xaml, windows-10, uwp

I am trying to set in the visual states a custom attached property I have tried several ways with the complete namespace, without, with the alias, etc. without success any idea?

```
xmlns:p="using:Controls.Views.Properties"
<RelativePanel x:Name="RootPanel" Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="VisualStateGroup">
            <VisualState x:Name="NarrowView">
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="0" />
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
     //This is where the value is not achieved
     <Setter Target="Text.(p:RelativeSize.Width)" Value="0.5"/>
```

It does not just fire any error, I can replace p: with j: and it doesn't crash, I do not know how to solve that.

This question is to finish the solution in here:  [Relative width for UI Elements with RelativePanel in XAML with UWP Apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31852833/relative-width-for-ui-elements-with-relativepanel-in-xaml-with-uwp-apps/31853821#31853821)

Comment: Can you give us more XAML (where is the 'Text' element), and the code you use for your custom attached property

Comment: Text is just a control inside the RelativePanel, watch the link about the other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31852833/relative-width-for-ui-elements-with-relativepanel-in-xaml-with-uwp-apps/31853821#31853821

Comment: Oh I see. OK, I believe this is a limitation, same as you cannot animate a *custom attached property*.

Comment: This needs to be FIXED. UWP is a joke. It doesn't even show any error.

Answer (score 2):

There is a way using the event and reflection:

XAML:

```
<VisualStateGroup x:Name="VisualStateGroup" CurrentStateChanged="VisualStateGroup_CurrentStateChanged">
```

Code:

```
private void VisualStateGroup_CurrentStateChanged(object sender, VisualStateChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var sbase in e.NewState.Setters)
        {
            var setter = sbase as Setter;
            var spath = setter.Target.Path.Path;
            var element = setter.Target.Target as FrameworkElement;

            if (spath.Contains(nameof(RelativeSize)))
            {
                string property = spath.Split('.').Last().TrimEnd(')');

                var prop = typeof(RelativeSize).GetMethod($"Set{property}");

                prop.Invoke(null, new object[] { element, setter.Value });
            }
        }
    }
```

It solves this case and you can adapt to multiple cases

Comment: Vote on the platform feature here: https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform/suggestions/35389138-visualstate-setters-should-support-custom-attached

Answer (score -2):

The short code is correct. Is RelativePanel the root element?

VisualStateManager must be placed in the root element:

```
<Page ...>
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="VisualStateGroup">
                <VisualState x:Name="NarrowView">
                    <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                        <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="0" />
                    </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <VisualState.Setters>//This is where the value is not achieved
                        <Setter Target="Text.(p:RelativeSize.Width)" Value="0.5" />
                        ...
                    </VisualState.Setters>
                </VisualState>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Comment: That works, the matter here is about custom attached properties in a setter are not caught by the Setter of the Visual State